# Creating a control like this

Tags: c++, c, winapi

How could I create a control that looks like this one:
[http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/4268/eeeeae.png http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/4268/eeeeae.png](http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/4268/eeeeae.png)

I just want that small end.
Thanks

Comment: With the gradient and rounded corners?

Comment: Whatever the default one is, i'm sure winapi can produce this using style combinations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's a Windows ComboBox control with a visual style applied to it, you can render its themed button wherever you like using [`DrawThemeBackground()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773289%28VS.85%29.aspx) and `CP_DROPDOWNBUTTON`.

Answer (score 1):

In your WndProc handle the WM_PAINT message. The easiest way using GDI is to have a ready to use image in your resources to load and drow on the window's DC. Little bit more complicated is to use GDI+, where you can draw rounded corners using Path object and gradient background using LinearGradientBrush.